# BPF program is not valid - pcap sniffing

Tags: pcap, packet-sniffers, sniffing, bpf

Hey everyone I'm trying to sniff packets using the pcap library. I have just one problem that I can not figure out: `ERROR: BPF program is not valid`.

[image: BPF program is not valid]

I'm trying to start the sniffing but this error is blocking me I searched on the web and found nothing.

My code is based after this program: https://github.com/levans248/packetSniffingAndSpoofing/blob/master/sniff.c

It is due to SEED labs I know people do not help when it is homework but I just need to figure why this is happening I have no clue.

```c
#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

void got_packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet)
{
    printf("Got a packet \n");
}

int main()
{
    pcap_t *handle;
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    struct bpf_program fp;
    char filter_exp[] = "ip proto icmp";
    bpf_u_int32 net;

    // Open live pcap session
    handle = pcap_open_live("enp0s3", BUFSIZ, 1, 1000, errbuf);
    // Compile Filter into the Berkeley Packet Filter (BPF)
    pcap_compile(handle, &fp, filter_exp, 0, net);

    if (pcap_setfilter(handle, &fp) == -1)
    {
        pcap_perror(handle, "ERROR");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Sniffing..
    pcap_loop(handle, -1, got_packet, NULL);
    pcap_close(handle);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That error just means your filter `ip proto icmp` has an incorrect syntax. Check the documentation to fix it.

Comment: it is the corrent syntax, I checked BPF syntax 
this is for IPV4
ip proto p
while p can be tcp,udp,icmp

Comment: The syntax is _not_ correct, and pchaigno is right. If you had bothered reading the documentation for `ip proto` in `man pcap-filter`, you would have found that `the identifiers tcp, udp, and icmp are also keywords and must be escaped via backslash (\).` So your filter should probably be something like `ip proto \icmp` or just `icmp`.

Comment: Note that an easy way to try your filter expression is to run it with tcpdump. `tcpdump -i eth0 ip proto '\icmp'` works, the version without the backslash (and the quotes, to prevent the shell to interpret the backslash) would not.

Comment: Well sir I tried every way it is still give an ERROR , i removed the exit line and it is Sniff without a filter, do really understand what to do , this is code was provided with this filter

Comment: when I use "icmp"` alone with the ip proto __  it does sniff but with no filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: ip proto doc - C-shell]

There was a SYNTAX mistake in the filter_exp ,
I was working on C-Shell so was needed to change to ip proto \icmp

Thank you very much everyone !

Comment: Glad you fixed it! If I may, try to copy the textual error messages or documentation extracts instead of inserting pictures for your future posts. This makes it better for future users (no risk of broken links), more accessible (not everyone displays/can see pictures in their browser), and easier to copy-paste for further research.